# Getting the refs work has been challenging

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In **asp.net core application**, I'm using  **"react": "16.4.1"** and **"typescript": "2.9.2"**. Somehow, whichever path I'm taking to get the **refs** to work isn't succeeding.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Here it is: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs
Can you show us example that not work from your code?

Comment: Please add some code here to understand what you have done and what the actual issue is.

Comment: @RubyYbur I've added an image. Thank you.

Comment: @HridayModi I've added an image. Thank you.

Comment: Do you try to run it anyway ?

Comment: @dungtranhcmus Yes, I get the error: 'myRef' does not exist on type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to execute the commands **"npm -i react-dom"** and **"npm install"**

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your @types/react to be compatible with react 16.4 as the current one is throwing the above error.

You can also try adding:

```
class .....{
private myRef;
constructor (props){
...
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Property createRef does not exist is the error.